# How do I run a MATLAB_kernel in an IPython notebook using Conda?

Tags: python, matlab, ipython, jupyter-notebook, conda

## Context

I want to use [this](https://github.com/Calysto/matlab_kernel) Matlab kernel in my IPython notebook.

I have installed the necessary packages using condo install

> /Users/johncosnett/anaconda

```
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/ioos matlab_kernel

conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/ioos pymatbridge
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

### Question

What do I need to do to run it?

in the Github README it says:

> "In the IPython notebook interface, select Matlab from the 'New' menu"

but when I do this, Matlab is not available. The only option is Python 3 my root environment.

Comment: Have you run `python -m matlab_kernel.install` inside your conda environment?

Comment: @ThomasK your instruction was one of several missing pieces in the puzzle eventually got the kernel up and running :)

Comment: the installation command that you provided didn't work anymore. I had to use `conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/pchrapka matlab_kernel`. When I used `python -m matlab_kernel.install`, I got the following error: `No module named matlab_kernel.install` but that must be related to having several conda environments.

Answer (score 0):

## For anyone else interested in getting this working in OS X

this [blog](http://anneurai.net/2015/11/12/matlab-based-ipython-notebooks/#comment-89) provides excellent instructions.

---

- Make sure you have Matlab already installed and working... this does 
  not work without it.
- Make sure you are in a conda environment with

  - python 3.4
  - Ipython 4.1.1
  - pymatbridge 0.5.2 ioos
  - jupyter 1.0.0

---

The bit that wasted hours of my life was pointing my version of MATLAB to the matlab_kernel.

To do: paste this into your Terminal then restart your terminal:

```
echo “export MATLAB_EXECUTABLE=/Applications/MATLAB_2015b.app/bin/matlab” >> ~/.bash_profile
```

> finally you can check the edits to your bash_profile with `open ~/.bash_profile`